# Runtime checks for android in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

How do i implement runtime checks in a Xamarin forms project for the android platform, most of my code is in the PCL. So how can i write checks for the apis being used since im not calling them form xamarin.android but from the PCL and i don't know the android specific apis being used?

Comment: Since you are already using dependency services, pass the API level back from one or implement the API level check in your Xamarin.Android code and not the PCL/NetStd code

Comment: You can use Device class for runtime check device type follow this link https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/platform-features/device/

Comment: But what do i place inside the runtime check? I don't know the apis in Lollipop. Also all my code and ui is in the PCL, so even if i knew the apis how would i reference the apis from the android project?